# Trying to omit 'na' rows in a specific column with na.omit. The function runs with no errors but doesn't omit the desired rows

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R and this is my first post on the website, I am trying to omit na rows from my data frame. I am using na.omit function which runs put doesn't omit the desired column.

My data frame looks as below, I want to remove "na" values from the Gene.Symbol Column only without affecting the other two columns.

I've tried

```
na.omit(data.frame, cols= Gene.Symbol(data.frame))
```

Which runs, but doesn't remove any rows, I know from looking at the data frame that there are about 19 rows with "na" so the command isn't working at all.

thanks for the help!

```
Gene.Symbol Diag.A      Rel.A
A2ML        173         17

na          02          95 

ABCA10      18          97 

ABCA4       14          na

ADCY2       81          98
```

Comment: is that a true `NA` in your `Gene.Symbol` column, or a text 'na'?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to exclude all missing values from N columns, `complete.cases` is another option. It returns a vector of TRUE's and FALSE's where TRUE are rows that don't have any NA in the selected columns. I find it has better documentation than `na.omit` and it's much clearer:

```r
tst <- mtcars[1:5, ]
tst$some_na <- c(NA, NA, 2, 2, 3)
tst$another_na <- c(NA, NA, 2, 2, NA)

# These are the columns you want to exclude `NA` from:
non_na <- complete.cases(tst[, c("some_na", "another_na")])

# No NA's
tst[non_na, ]
#>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb some_na
#> Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       2
#> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       2
#>                another_na
#> Datsun 710              2
#> Hornet 4 Drive          2
```